# highcharts solid gauge: bigger tick marks

Tags: css, highcharts

I am making a solid gauge with highcharts. I am trying to make the ticks long enough to span both data series. The goal is for a white line to cut through the colored bands at 10, 6, 2.9, and 0%. Notice how at 2.9%, the tick doesn't go all the way through (even though the length is set to 100).

I have tried `yAxis.tickLength` to make the ticks longer, to no avail. I also tried `yAxis.tickPosition: 'inside'`. That doesn't solve it either. Here is my JSFiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/ncernek/wy6bo63p/2/

Thank you for your help.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add dummy second pane and yAxis, then ticks will be both inside and outside - because in fact there will be 2 ticks looking like one.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Lcz6juea/

And if I get wrong index of ticks (over series) then you could use this code without `zIndex` set for axes: http://jsfiddle.net/Lcz6juea/1/

```js
$(function() {

  // Uncomment to style it like Apple Watch
  /*
  if (!Highcharts.theme) {
      Highcharts.setOptions({
          chart: {
              backgroundColor: 'black'
          },
          colors: ['#F62366', '#9DFF02', '#0CCDD6'],
          title: {
              style: {
                  color: 'silver'
              }
          },
          tooltip: {
              style: {
                  color: 'silver'
              }
          }
      });
  }
  // */

  Highcharts.setOptions({
    chart: {
      backgroundColor: 'white'
    },
    colors: ['#FE670A', '#0277a0', 'white']
  });

  Highcharts.chart('container', {

    chart: {
      type: 'solidgauge',
      marginTop: 50
    },

    title: {
      text: 'Discepant Reads',
      style: {
        fontSize: '24px'
      }
    },

    tooltip: {
      borderWidth: 0,
      backgroundColor: 'none',
      shadow: false,
      style: {
        fontSize: '16px'
      },
      pointFormat: '{series.name}<br><span style="font-size:2em; color: {point.color}; font-weight: bold; text-align: center">{point.y}%</span>',
      positioner: function(labelWidth, labelHeight) {
        return {
          x: 200 - labelWidth / 2,
          y: 180
        };
      }
    },

    pane: [{
      startAngle: -140,
      endAngle: 140,
      background: [{ // Track for Move
        outerRadius: '112%',
        innerRadius: '88%',
        backgroundColor: Highcharts.Color(Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]).setOpacity(0.3).get(),
        borderWidth: 0,
        shape: 'arc'
      }, { // Track for Exercise
        outerRadius: '87%',
        innerRadius: '63%',
        backgroundColor: Highcharts.Color(Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]).setOpacity(0.3).get(),
        borderWidth: 0,
        shape: 'arc'
      }, { // Track for Stand
        outerRadius: '62%',
        innerRadius: '38%',
        backgroundColor: Highcharts.Color(Highcharts.getOptions().colors[2]).setOpacity(0.3).get(),
        borderWidth: 0,
        shape: 'arc'
      }]
    }, {
      startAngle: -140,
      endAngle: 140,
      size: '95%',
      background: []
    }],

    yAxis: [{
      reversed: true,
      min: 0,
      max: 10,
      lineWidth: 0,
      tickLength: 100,
      tickWidth: 4,
      tickColor: 'white',
      tickPosition: 'outside',
      minorTickLength: 0,
      tickPositions: [0, 2.9, 6, 10],
      zIndex: 4,
      labels: {
        distance: 30,
        enabled: true,
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        format: '{value} %',
        style: {
          fontSize: 16
        }
      }
    }, {
      pane: 1,
      linkedTo: 0,

      reversed: true,
      min: 0,
      max: 10,
      lineWidth: 0,
      tickLength: 100,
      tickWidth: 4,
      tickColor: 'white',
      tickPosition: 'inside',
      minorTickLength: 0,
      tickPositions: [0, 2.9, 6, 10],
      zIndex: 4,
      labels: {
        enabled: false
      }
    }],

    plotOptions: {
      solidgauge: {
        borderWidth: '34px',
        dataLabels: {
          enabled: false
        },
        linecap: 'round',
        stickyTracking: false
      }
    },

    series: [{
      name: 'Your Score',
      borderColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0],
      data: [{
        color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0],
        radius: '100%',
        innerRadius: '100%',
        y: 4
      }],
      dataLabels: {
        borderRadius: 0,
        backgroundColor: "#fff",
        borderWidth: 0,
        borderColor: "#FFF",
        style: {
          fontSize: "50px"
        },
        color: "grey",
        crop: true,
        formatter: function() {
          var s;
          s = '<span style="font-size: 50px;">' + this.point.y + '</span>';
          return s;
        },
        y: -30,
        zIndex: 90
      }
    }, {
      name: 'Department Average',
      borderColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1],
      data: [{
        color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1],
        radius: '75%',
        innerRadius: '75%',
        y: 6
      }]
    }, {
      name: '',
      borderColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[2],
      data: [{
        color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[2],
        radius: '50%',
        innerRadius: '50%',
        y: 50
      }]
    }]
  });


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/solid-gauge.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Kacper. Checkout another solution I found: I reformatted the background and plotbands so they are sized smaller and can be more easily configuered: jsfiddle.net/ncernek/wy6bo63p/11

Answer (score 0):

**Using JavaScript**

```
Highcharts.wrap(Highcharts.Tick.prototype, 'getMarkPath', function (prev, x, y, tickLength, tickWidth, horiz, renderer) {
    return renderer.rect(x, y, 2, 80, 0)
             .attr({
               'stroke-width': 2,
               stroke: 'white',
               zIndex: 4,
               style: 'transform: rotateZ(45deg) translateY(-290px)'
             }).add();
});
```

You'd have to figure out a way to override each tick, but it's doable.

--

**Using CSS**

The (almost) pure CSS way is to target the exact SVG path and apply a transform to it. By no means is this way ideal, but it does provide a way to get the job done.

```
.highcharts-axis path:nth-child(2) {
  transform: scale3d(1.6, 1, 1) rotateY(-59.7deg) translate(0, 25px);
  stroke-width: 2;
}

.highcharts-axis path:nth-child(3) {
  transform: scale3d(3.9, 1, 1) rotateY(-70deg) translate(0, 56px);
  stroke-width: 2;
}
```

You would also have to adjust the `zIndex` attribute of the `yAxis` so that the redrawn ticks are on top of the other paths:

```
yAxis: {
  ...
  zIndex: 4
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but that makes the tick wider, not longer.

Comment: I've given it another go!

Comment: Andy, thanks for the suggestion. This solution looks like it makes new ticks and ignores the highcharts' ticks. It seems like a hack that's gonna get me into trouble. Is it responsive? Perhaps Highcharts draws its ticks with this limitation.

Comment: It's definitely a hack, but my research found no elegant way to achieve this. I have not tested responsiveness, as I didn't know it was a requirement. I'll have a look and get back to you.

Comment: Thanks Andy. Checkout a solution I found: I reformatted the background and plotbands so they are sized smaller: http://jsfiddle.net/ncernek/wy6bo63p/11/